# Show that $(Au,Bv)=(u,A^tBv)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

Let $ A, B $ be matrices of order $ n $, and $ \vec{u}, \vec{v} $ vectors from euclidean space $ \mathbb{R}^n $, then $ (Au,Bv) = (u,A^tBv) $

pd. $(\cdot ,\cdot)$ is my notation for inner product, and $ A^t $ is the transpose of $A$

I don't know how to demonstrate that, and I'm not sure if it's true.

There's my demo, I can't complete it. Maybe I'm not using the right definitions,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know the definition of $\langle Au, Bv\rangle$?

Comment: i don't think so

Comment: It's hard to prove things without knowing the definition. Why don't you look it up for starters? There are several (though similar) canonical ways of defining the inner product.

Comment: I know something about inner products, i just have a doubt about this prop, 'cause i can't make it true, maybe i'm forgeting some definition of transposed matrices in my demo,

Comment: One possible definition is $\langle x, y\rangle:=y^Tx$ (assuming it's a real vector space).

Comment: letting y^t.x be a vector? i thought that wasn't possible, by definition

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The definition is for $x,y\in \mathbb R^{n\times 1}$. It yields a $1\times 1$ matrix which can be identified with a scalar.

Comment: i understeand, my mistake, sorry. But that's a general definition or just for conventional inner product? Can i use that for my formal demo?

Comment: There are several possible inner products. One of them is that one, a canonical one. I'm assuming that the question is asking you to prove this regarding this inner product.

Comment: there's a picture of my demo, i'm gonna try with that,

Comment: I didn't read it because you made it more complicated than it is necessary. Note the following: $\langle Au,Bv\rangle=(Bv)^TAu=v^TB^TAu=\ldots =\langle u,A^TBv\rangle$. Try to fill in the gaps.

Comment: I got it! (Au,Bv)= (Bv)^t Au = v^t B^t Au, then, (v^t B^t Au)^t = (au)^t (v^t B^t)^t = u^t A^t Bv = (A^t Bv, u) = (u, A^t Bv) Thanks! It's amazing, :)

Comment: That's fine but I would have gone for $$\langle Au,Bv\rangle=(Bv)^TAu=v^TB^TAu=v^TB^T\left(A^T\right)^Tu=(A^TBv)^Tu =\langle u,A^TBv\rangle.$$

Comment: It would be good if you posted an answer to your question yourself, so this question doesn't come up as unanswered. I see you're a new user here. Please read about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).